# Read a json file with bash

Tags: json, bash

I kwould like to read the json file from http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/alfred.json in bash and separate it into files named by hostname of each element in that json string.

How do I read json with bash?

Comment: json came slightly after bash, but "node -p" will eval stdIn as JS, and print the output to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python one-liner in similar way like (I haven't checked):

```
curl -s http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/alfred.json | python -c '
import json, sys
tbl=json.load(sys.stdin)
for t in tbl:
  with open(tbl[t]["hostname"], "wb") as fp:
    json.dump(tbl[t], fp)
'
```

Comment: Rubo77 was pretty clear. He asked to do it with bash in both the title and the body. Where did python come from?

Comment: I like the python alternative, because this would use only one instance

Comment: @rubo77 This is not the answer to your question though.

Comment: Yes I know but it is the solution I will finally use. So I marked this one. That's how I understood the green hook.

Comment: @jww here python plays the role of a helper tool, like jq, curl, grep, sed or whatever. Limiting yourself only with bash (which is basically perfect as glue but not for the task) to read / write json doesn't look effective and right solution

Comment: @rubo77 thanks for accepted, I just wanted to show alternative that I'd go with ...

Comment: Jsawk is a nice little tool for json processing in bash.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I read json with bash?

You can use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for that. First thing you have to do is extract the list of hostnames and save it to a bash array. Running a loop on that array you would then run again a query for each hostname to extract each element based on them and save the data through redirection with the filename based on them as well.

Comment: I am so far `cat alfred.json |jq '.[] | {network:.network, hardware: .hardware, location: .location, owner: .owner, hostname: .hostname}'` so How do I get the output into separate files then?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with two instances of `jq` -- one listing hostnames, and another (inside the loop) extracting individual entries.

This is, alas, a bit inefficient (since it means rereading the file from the top for each record to extract).

```
while read -r hostname; do
  [[ $hostname = */* ]] && continue # paranoia; see comments
  jq --arg hostname "$hostname" \
     '.[] | select(.hostname == $hostname)' <alfred.json >"out-${hostname}.json"
done < <(jq -r '.[] | .hostname' <alfred.json)
```

(The `out-` prefix prevents `alfred.json` from being overwritten if it includes an entry for a host named `alfred`).

Comment: Yes jq is a nice tool, but it seems it won't work with just one `jq` instance. So in the end I will use python, I think

Comment: @rubo77, indeed; personally, I'd probably have written this tool from python to begin with, rather than as a shell script calling something else.

Comment: I would use a subfolder to store the files: `nodes='cat alfred.json';
files=logs/nodes;
mkdir -p $files;
$nodes|jq '.[].network.mac'|while read i; do 
 $nodes |jq '.['$i']' > $files/$($nodes |jq '.['$i'].hostname');
done
`

Comment: @rubo77, the code you pasted there is somewhat broken (albeit most of those bugs being obscure/hard to hit, but better to be robust even against obscure inputs when you're working with untrusted data off the Internet). I used `--arg` in my sample for a reason -- otherwise, your `$i` can be treated as part of the jq query, rather than part of a value. Also, expansions need to be quoted to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion, and `read` unescapes backslash expansions unless the `-r` argument is passed.

Comment: @ruby77, ...actually, since you're using random-off-the-Internet data, it'd also be worth being cautious about your data containing malicious "hostnames" like `../../../../../../etc/passwd`; see the according edit. :)

Comment: I do create this alfred.json file myself, and it doesnt contain any quotes. my script works: 
 (see https://gist.github.com/rubo77/082dacc5a4858528b09f)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58300/discussion-between-rubo77-and-charles-duffy).